# ErrorProvider tooltip message

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip, errorprovider

I am new to c# and I have this problem:

I have here a ***textbox with errorProvider and a label*** above my textbox..

After validating the value in my textbox, whenever value entered is not acceptable, error icon should appear at the right side of the label with its tooltip message shown when icon is hovered.

But whenever I click the **error icon**, its **tooltip message** will be (disposed? or) **disappear** and will not reappear even if the mouse pointer is moved away from the error icon and hovered again to the icon. It will just reappear when the whole window is closed and reopened again. Its a bit annoying.

How can I make it not disappear whenever error icon is clicked? Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for a solution to this problem I've found out that this issue on errorProvider tooltip message is *[reported as bug to connect.microsoft.com on "8/29/2006 11:16:27 AM" but has already been closed "as won't fix"](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/188945/errorprovider-tooltip-disappears-after-mouse-pointer-is-left-on-error-icon-for-over-ten-seconds)*.[it's already 5 years since the feedback..(-_-)] 
I think it's now the time they "should fix this bug because it is impeding the usage of the errorprovider control."

I have also found a [**workaround that'll solve this issue**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17102/ErrorProvider-Fix-for-Disappearing-ToolTip).

I hope this helps and also they will fix this issue sooner.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior of Windows tooltips, they are shown when you hover some icon in the system as a help message for the illustrated command.

ErrorProvider control for Windows Forms just show a non-clickable icon near another control to inform the user about an invalid input and its tooltip will have the common Windows icon behavior.

This method is ineffective if you must get the error message with clicks, because this control do not expose to observers any click or mouse methods, so you'll have to follow another way.

Comment: this is about errorProvider with its tooltip message.
FYI, there are different behaviors of errorProviders in different OSs --like win7 and win xp..
In Windows7, i notice that the errorProviders and its tooltip messages just behave normally..but
in Windowsxp, errorProviders' tooltip messages just disappear after error icons have been clicked.

What I wanted is to make errorProviders behavior in winxp same as with win7. :) Thank you.